# Find out which row fails on adding a constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

For this error message, is there a way for mysqlimport to output the specific row that fails the constraint? It's good for debugging. Otherwise, I don't know which row has this problem.

```
mysqlimport: Error: 1452, Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bwordDS`.`Category_Term`, CONSTRAINT `FK_qn1crq26sr0hqm5q2p7nfvdu1` FOREIGN KEY (`categories_id`) REFERENCES `Category` (`id`)), when using table: Category_Term
```

Answer (score 2):

First check if Category table exist where you are trying to import this data.

if Category table exists then need to check that all category_id in this table should exist in Category table as id.

Better option is to import first category table and then this table.

In generic first all parent tables data should import then child tables.

A dirty way is as per below which is not recommended-

```
set foreign_key_checks=0;
import data here;
set foreign_key_checks=1;
```

**Just to know which row is creating problem-**

Below query will provide you problematic rows.

```
SELECT a.category_id FROM Category_Term a 
  LEFT JOIN Category b ON a.category_id=b.id 
  WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

Note: Assuming category_id in category_term and id in category tables will be indexed.

Comment: "check that all category_id in this table should exist in Category table as id.". I want to do this too. It's a large table. I have to write separate code to do this? It would be nice if mysqlimport can report the very first row that encounters this problem.

Comment: no I think it will not do auto, but you can get by my updated query.....if this query is taking time...then just insert single column from both tables in some temp tables and then you can use this query on newly created temp tables..it will be fast.

Comment: The problem is that, due to the importing error, the Category_Term table is now empty. Nothing imported, so can't check through a select statement.

Comment: you can check it on source server....or first import category table then category_term table or first import both tables on some testing server check problematic rows there...

Comment: yes, I think I have to write a program to check, since the table is large.

Answer (score 1):

I used the sample query provided by @Zafar, but I added `DISTINCT` to SELECT as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT countries.city_id 
    FROM countries 
    LEFT JOIN cities ON countries.city_id=city.id 
    WHERE city.id IS NULL;
```